# Storing and saving day-of-week/time - value pairs in Java

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm scraping some data from a [webpage](http://aikataulut.hsl.fi/pysakit/en/1020249.html) and would like to save it in structure. My data is a a collection of day/time value pairs example:

```
Monday  07:15   312
Monday  07:20   553
Monday  09:55   312
Tuesday 09:55   312
```

I don't need to store the date, just the day of the week and the 24h time. I'd like to be a be able to query this collection to get the next pair. For example, if I queried it `Tuesday, 07:00`, I should get the next closest record i.e. `Tuesday, 09:55`.

I'm quite lost as to what would be a nice way to store this information without resorting to SQLite or some equivalent.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use SQLite?

Comment: ...because it is a pain to manage with the db migrations and having to resort to using a whole db instead of a simple collection that I could serialize sounds a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Panky1986's advice and used an `EnumMap` containing a `TreeMap` to store the hours and a nested `TreeMap` inside that to store the minutes which in turn stores the data.

```
/* This is the enumeration which tracks the days */
public enum DAY {WEEKDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY};

/* This is the map that stores the timings */
private EnumMap<DAY, TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>>> mapDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, i would opt for a tree map where in i can store the Day of the month as Key and time as its value. The day can be an enum storing the seven values of Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday and Sunday while the value can be a timestamp storing the hours and minutes.

The collection would be a sorted hash map or a tree map (or a sorted EnumMap which would be better than other two options).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi mridang,
just for more clarification. use an enum map to store your data. As you wrote your enum would look like this
public enum DAYTIME {
  MONDAY(System.currentTimeMillis()), ;

  Food(int price) {
   this.price = price;
  }

  private final int price;

  public int getPrice() {
   return price;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

just for more clarification. use an enum map to store your data. Just modify your enum like this
public enum DAYTIME {
        MONDAY(System.currentTimeMillis()),TUESDAY(System.currentTimeMillis()),OTHER_WEEKDAYS(System.currentTimeMillis());

```
    DAYTIME(Long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    private final Long timeInMillis;

    public Long getTimeInMillis() {
        return time ;
    }
}
```

Now DayTime when invoked will return the enum with the day and the current time stamp. I think this fulfills the requirement on the time storage side.

Your EnumMap would be like this

```
private EnumMap<DAYTIME, Object> mapDays;
```

Here Object represents any data you wish to save in the db be it another list/map/other collection
You now need to write a utility that will sort the stored map on enum time field.
This way you can get the next element by specifying day and time.